# Why does the map function in MapReduce take two parameters?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, parallel-computing

I am playing around with MapReduce and wanted to ask why the `map` function takes two inputs `(key, value)`? Why not just pass along the value?

Specifically, if you look at the [word count example on Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Examples) you will see that the map function is:

```
function map(String name, String document):
// name: document name
// document: document contents
  for each word w in document:
    emit (w, 1)
```

However, the function never does anything with the parameter "name". Why even pass it in?

Comment: This is almost a pure programming question (which would be offtopic here, but ontopic on [SO]) but it seems to allow some general answers, so I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me quote the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/) (emphasis mine):

> *Map* You write a map function that runs once for each input value. It **returns a collection of name-value pairs** which are passed on to the next stage. If there are many, many input values, then this function runs many, many times. The framework divides up the input so that subsets are **handled in parallel on multiple instances of your application**. A typical map function could count things that occur in each input value that matches some filter.

So there are two immediate uses I can imagine:

- Use the "chunk" name in the returned names. For example, you might want to distinguish `bible_author` from `fiftyshadesofgrey_author` in the result.
- Identify "subprocesses". If anything goes wrong (and something *will* go wrong) an error message like "Error processing `bible`: Illegal character at position 666" is obviously only useful if you include the document name.

And, of course, you may also want to use the name in the actual computation. A general API should cover that case.

Comment: Ah I see, so while it's strictly not needed for the word count algorithm, it is used by the general API and debugging. Got it. At least now I know I'm not missing anything!